# API Facebook:invite multiple users to a event

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm tried invite multiple users to a event. 
reading the documentation facebook, I found this:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited

I wrote the following code(that does not works):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
  'cookie' => true,
));

if ($user = $facebook->getUser()) {
    $friends = $facebook -> api('/me/friends');
    $e_id = ""; //the event id
    $friends = $friends['data'];
    $e_details = $facebook -> api("/{$e_id}"); //information about the event
    for($ids = null,$i = 0,$len = count($friends); $i < $len; $i++) {
                $friend = $friends[$i];
                $ids .= $friend['id'].',';
    }
    $data = $facebook -> api("/{$e_id}/invited?users={$ids}", 'POST');
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 

} else {
     $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'create_event'));

}
```

I'm getting the fowllowing error:

**Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Permissions error thrown in**

what's the permission that he is saying? of according to the documentation only one permission is necessary, which I set.

Can someone point out my error? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try: add `rsvp_even` in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first try and store the ids in an array not sure if the trailing comma is messing with it. Also remove your self if it is in the list. you can also test the call at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fgroups to see if there is anything else to test for. Maybe add a test to double check if the user has the create_event permission as well.

```
if ($user = $facebook->getUser()) {
    $friends = $facebook -> api('/me/friends');
    $e_id = ""; //the event id
    $friends = $friends['data'];
    $e_details = $facebook -> api("/{$e_id}"); //information about the event
    for($ids = null,$i = 0,$len = count($friends); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $friend = $friends[$i];
        if($user != $friend['id']){
            $ids[] = $friend['id'];
        }
    }
    $data = $facebook -> api("/{$e_id}/invited", 'POST', array("users"=>implode(",", $ids)));
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'create_event'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mauvaise gestion des virgule je pense, là $ids se termine par une virgule, essaye plutôt comme ça :

```
for($ids = null,$i = 0,$len = count($friends); $i < $len; $i++) {
            $friend = $friends[$i];
            if ($ids)$ids.=',';
            $ids .= $friend['id'];
}
```

Et il faut limiter les invitations à 100 par "boucle" si on croit la FAQ de google sur les nouvelles limitations d'invitations